# Vectorized moving window on 2D array in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I am apply an operation on a moving window of constant size across a 2D array.  Is there an efficient vectorize-like operation I can implement to do this without looping in Python?  My current structure looks something like this

```
 for i in range(1,xmax-1):
     for j in range(1,ymax-1):
        out[i][j] = f(in[i][j],in[i+1][j],in[i-1][j],in[i][j+1],in[i][j-1],...)
```

The comments that *eat* left in this question allude to the possibility of vectorizing this operation this, but without further details [vectorized indexing/slicing in numpy/scipy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877008/vectorized-indexing-slicing-in-numpy-scipy)

Comment: For applying a generic NumPy ufunc, you can put every block into a column, similar to MATLAB has with [`im2col`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2col.html). A vectorized implementation of the same in NumPy/Python is listed in [`Implement Matlab's im2col 'sliding' in Python`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30109068/implement-matlabs-im2col-sliding-in-python). Also, you can look [`here`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34327984/3293881) to see some examples.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can express the function

```
f(in[i][j],in[i+1][j],in[i-1][j],in[i][j+1],in[i][j-1],…)
```

as a linear operator, you could use scipy's [signal.convolve2d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html) function to do exactly that. For instance, say you have an 50x50 array, A, and you want to calculate a second array B where each of its element `b[ij]` is the average over `a[i,j], a[(i-1),j], a[i,(j-1)], a[(i-1),(j-1)]` from the array A. You could do that simply doing :

```
A = # your first array
B = numpy.ones((2,2))/4
C = scipy.signal.convolve2d(A,B, 'valid')
```

When the convolution is performed, the array B "slides" across A, multiplying the corresponding elements and summing up the result. Because of border effects, you must be careful when using the resulting array C. Here, C is of shape 49x49, because of the `'valid'` argument in `convolve2d`, to discard the first row and column since they contain border effects. If you wanted to have a 50x50 array, without discarding, you would swap that argument for `'same'`

**EDIT**: Perhaps if you could tell me more about that function you need, I could help you more specifically in turning it into an array that would be used to do the 2D convolution.

Hope that helps!

Comment: use fftconvolve instead of convolve2d to make it faster

Answer (score 16):

You can use the rolling window technique as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7100681/7550928), [here](http://www.rigtorp.se/2011/01/01/rolling-statistics-numpy.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811183/rolling-window-for-1d-arrays-in-numpy), but for 2D array.

The source code for 2D rolling window in NumPy:

```
# Rolling window for 2D arrays in NumPy
import numpy as np

def rolling_window(a, shape):  # rolling window for 2D array
    s = (a.shape[0] - shape[0] + 1,) + (a.shape[1] - shape[1] + 1,) + shape
    strides = a.strides + a.strides
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=s, strides=strides)

a = np.array([[0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
              [6,  7,  8,  9, 10,  11],
              [12, 13, 14, 15, 7,   8],
              [18, 19, 20, 21, 13, 14],
              [24, 25, 26, 27, 19, 20],
              [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]], dtype=np.int)
b = np.arange(36, dtype=np.float).reshape(6,6)
present = np.array([[7,8],[13,14],[19,20]], dtype=np.int)
absent  = np.array([[7,8],[42,14],[19,20]], dtype=np.int)

found = np.all(np.all(rolling_window(a, present.shape) == present, axis=2), axis=2)
print(np.transpose(found.nonzero()))
found = np.all(np.all(rolling_window(b, present.shape) == present, axis=2), axis=2)
print(np.transpose(found.nonzero()))
found = np.all(np.all(rolling_window(a, absent.shape) == absent, axis=2), axis=2)
print(np.transpose(found.nonzero()))
```

Array `present` is occurred in array `a` two times on [1,1] and [2,4].

More examples in my CoLab notebook ["Rolling window on NumPy arrays without `for` loops"](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Zru_-zzbtylgitbwxbi0eDBNhwr8qYl6).

Comment: It looks like the `rolling_window` function is implemented at [numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html) as of numpy 1.20.0