# Efficiently applying function over moving window numpy array

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, numpy

I have around 100,000 two dimensional arrays where I need to apply local filters. Both dimensions have an even size and the window is over a 2x2 piece and shifts 2 pieces further, so that every element is in a window once. The output is a binary two dimensional array of the same size and my filter is a binary 2x2 piece as well. The parts of my filter that are a 0 will map to a 0, the parts of my filter that is a 1 all map to a 1 if they have the same value and map to 0 if they are not all the same. Here is an example:

```
Filter:  0 1     Array to filter:  1 2 3 2    Output:  0 1 0 0
         1 0                       2 3 3 3             1 0 0 0
```

Of course I can do this using a double for loop however this is very inefficient and there has to be a better way. I read this: [Vectorized moving window on 2D array in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174467/vectorized-moving-window-on-2d-array-in-numpy) however I am uncertain how I would apply that to my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split each `2x2` subarray and then reshape such that each windowed block becomes a row in a `2D` array. 
From each row, extract out the elements corresponding to `f==1` positions using [`boolean indexing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays).
Then, look to see if all extracted elements are identical along each row, to give us a mask. Use this mask to multiply with `f` for the final binary output after reshaping.

Thus, assuming `f` as the filter array and `A` as the data array, a vectorized implementation to follow such steps would look like this -

```
# Setup size parameters
M = A.shape[0]
Mh = M/2
N = A.shape[1]/2

# Reshape input array to 4D such that the last two axes represent the 
# windowed block at each iteration of the intended operation      
A4D = A.reshape(-1,2,N,2).swapaxes(1,2)

# Determine the binary array whether all elements mapped against 1 
# in the filter array are the same elements or not
S = (np.diff(A4D.reshape(-1,4)[:,f.ravel()==1],1)==0).all(1)

# Finally multiply the binary array with f to get desired binary output
out = (S.reshape(Mh,N)[:,None,:,None]*f[:,None,:]).reshape(M,-1)
```

Sample run -

1) Inputs :

```
In [58]: A
Out[58]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1],
       [1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2],
       [1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1]])

In [59]: f
Out[59]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 1]])
```

2) Intermediate outputs :

```
In [60]: A4D
Out[60]: 
array([[[[1, 1],
         [1, 1]],

        [[1, 1],
         [3, 1]],

        [[2, 1],
         [2, 2]]],


       [[[1, 3],
         [3, 3]],

        [[3, 3],
         [3, 3]],

        [[2, 3],
         [3, 1]]]])

In [61]: S
Out[61]: array([ True, False, False,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

3) Final output :

```
In [62]: out
Out[62]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: The same approach can be done with `np.kron(~np.any(np.diff(A4D[...,f==1]), -1), f)` ;-)

Comment: @morningsun Ah yes the `kron` for the multiplication at the last step! Thanks!