# Numpy rolling window over 2D array, as a 1D array with nested array as data values

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, sliding-window

When using `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`, how can I manage 2D a array with the nested arrays as data values? Is there a preferable **efficient** approach?

Specifically, if I have a 2D `np.array` looking as follows, where each data item in a 1D array is an array of length 2:

```
[[1., 2.],[3., 4.],[5.,6.],[7.,8.],[9.,10.]...]
```

I want to reshape for rolling over as follows:

```
[[[1., 2.],[3., 4.],[5.,6.]],
 [[3., 4.],[5.,6.],[7.,8.]],
 [[5.,6.],[7.,8.],[9.,10.]],
  ...
]
```

I have had a look at similar answers (e.g. [this rolling window function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6811241/6334309)), however in use I cannot leave the inner array/tuples untouched.

For example with a window length of `3`: I have tried a `shape` of `(len(seq)+3-1, 3, 2)` and a `stride` of `(2 * 8, 2 * 8, 8)`, but no luck. Maybe I am missing something obvious?

Cheers.

---

**EDIT:** It is easy to produce a functionally identical solution using Python built-ins (which can be optimised using e.g. `np.arange` similar to Divakar's solution), however, what about using `as_strided`? From my understanding, this could be used for a highly efficient solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What was wrong with your `as_strided` trial?  It works for me.

```
In [28]: x=np.arange(1,11.).reshape(5,2)
In [29]: x.shape
Out[29]: (5, 2)
In [30]: x.strides
Out[30]: (16, 8)
In [31]: np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(x,shape=(3,3,2),strides=(16,16,8))
Out[31]: 
array([[[  1.,   2.],
        [  3.,   4.],
        [  5.,   6.]],

       [[  3.,   4.],
        [  5.,   6.],
        [  7.,   8.]],

       [[  5.,   6.],
        [  7.,   8.],
        [  9.,  10.]]])
```

On my first edit I used an `int` array, so had to use `(8,8,4)` for the strides.

Your shape could be wrong.  If too large it starts seeing values off the end of the data buffer.

```
   [[  7.00000000e+000,   8.00000000e+000],
    [  9.00000000e+000,   1.00000000e+001],
    [  8.19968827e-257,   5.30498948e-313]]])
```

Here it just alters the display method, the `7, 8, 9, 10` are still there.    Writing those those slots could be dangerous, messing up other parts of your code.  `as_strided` is best if used for read-only purposes.  Writes/sets are trickier.

Comment: Hm, maybe I missed something very obvious... Thanks for playing around, I will verify as soon as possible! Unfortunately I have been too busy to sit down with the associated project over the last day.

Comment: Thanks, I indeed answered my own question and was too stupid to realise - sigh. In the end, this didn't really bring any performance to the table - I'll need to revisit if using a more complex/higher dimension data structure, or maybe just larger data sets.

Answer (score 4):

IIUC you could do something like this -

```
def rolling_window2D(a,n):
    # a: 2D Input array 
    # n: Group/sliding window length
    return a[np.arange(a.shape[0]-n+1)[:,None] + np.arange(n)]
```

Sample run -

```
In [110]: a
Out[110]: 
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 3,  4],
       [ 5,  6],
       [ 7,  8],
       [ 9, 10]])

In [111]: rolling_window2D(a,3)
Out[111]: 
array([[[ 1,  2],
        [ 3,  4],
        [ 5,  6]],

       [[ 3,  4],
        [ 5,  6],
        [ 7,  8]],

       [[ 5,  6],
        [ 7,  8],
        [ 9, 10]]])
```

Comment: Thanks, this is functionally correct! Performance-wise, however, is this not inferior to a `as_strided` solution as I was attempting to achieve? Clearly this should be faster than any built-in `range` solution, however.

Comment: @Kappers Well I haven't really played around with `strides` much, so I can't comment on the performance aspect. So, at the least consider this as an alternative to strides in case `strides` method isn't working out for you, that's what I gathered from the question.

Answer (score 0):

You task is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46237736/7550928). So I slightly changed it.

```
# Rolling window for 2D arrays in NumPy
import numpy as np

def rolling_window(a, shape):  # rolling window for 2D array
    s = (a.shape[0] - shape[0] + 1,) + (a.shape[1] - shape[1] + 1,) + shape
    strides = a.strides + a.strides
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=s, strides=strides)

x = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[11,12]])
y = np.array([[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]])
found = np.all(np.all(rolling_window(x, y.shape) == y, axis=2), axis=2)
print(found.nonzero()[0])
```