# Efficiently subset a 2D numpy array iteratively

Tags: python, numpy, performance, nested-loops

I have a large image on which I want to perform an operation from a moving window over the whole window. Here is a reproducible example:

Given an array named `image` with shape (5, 5), I need to extract subsets from the array in 3x3 windows.

```
import numpy as np

# example dada
image = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5]])
```

**Out[1]:**

```
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
```

For a 3x3 window the first subset is:

```
# first iteration
window_size = 3
image[0:window_size, 0:window_size] # from 1st to 3th row and from 1st to 3th col
```

**Out[2]:**

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

So I can access to the different subsets using a nested loop:

```
for i in range(0, image.shape[0]-window_size+1):
   for j in range(0, image.shape[1]-window_size+1):
      a = (j,i)     # top left value
      b = (j,i+window_size)   # top right value
      c = (j+window_size,i)   # bottom left value
      d = (j+window_size,i+window_size) # bottom right value
      print('Window position', a,b,c,d)
      subset = image[i:i+window_size, j:j+window_size]
      print(subset)
```

Is there a more efficient way to perform this operation and avoid doing these two loops?

Comment: https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html — I don’t know if this is much faster, the docs do warn about it being slower than specialized solutions like the convolution.

Comment: You can use `np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(image, (3, 3))`, but it depends what you want to do with that…

Comment: Btw, your code for slicing is incorrect, this should be: `image[i:i+window_size, j:j+window_size]`

Comment: Your approach is what I am waiting for. Thank you very much. PS: I fixed the error in the reproducible code.

Comment: There are several other questions about vectorizing moving windows on arrays that you should reference, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722324/sliding-window-of-m-by-n-shape-numpy-ndarray), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174467/vectorized-moving-window-on-2d-array-in-numpy), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48215914/vectorized-2-d-moving-window-in-numpy-including-edges)

Comment: I didn't know you can use tuples to index in this way, so I tried running you code. As I expected, `image[a:b,a:c]` doesn't work. That should probably be `image[a[0]:d[0],a[1]:d[1]]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @CrisLuengo and @mozway comments I can answer my own question. Indeed the dedicated function `np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view` is more efficient than a nested loop. Here is a small timing test with a window size of 3x3 for arias of 100x100, 1000x1000 and 10000x10000.

```
import numpy as np
import time

image = np.random.random((10000, 10000))
window_size = 3

# nested loop
start = time.time()
subsets = []
for i in range(0, image.shape[0]-window_size+1):
   for j in range(0, image.shape[1]-window_size+1):
      subset = image[i:i+window_size, j:j+window_size]
      subsets.append(subset)
end = time.time()
print(end - start)

# dedicated function
start = time.time()
subset = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(image, (window_size, window_size))
subsets = subset.reshape(subset.shape[0]*subset.shape[1], window_size, window_size)
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

[image]

However, there may be an even more efficient solution using `scipy.ndimage.generic_filter`. This function allows to apply a user-defined function to the different positions of the window. If I find a better solution with this approach I will update my answer.

Comment: Consider using `time.perf_counter()` if you are trying to measure performance of approaches

Answer (score -2):

Try these steps:

```
import numpy as np

# example data
image = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])

# Define the window size
window_size = 3

# Calculate the number of rows and columns in the output array
output_shape = (image.shape[0] - window_size + 1, image.shape[1] - 
window_size + 1)

# Create an empty array to store the subsets
subsets = np.empty(output_shape, dtype=object)

# Extract subsets using nested loops
for i in range(output_shape[0]):
    for j in range(output_shape[1]):
        subsets[i, j] = image[i:i + window_size, j:j + window_size]

# Print the extracted subsets
for i in range(output_shape[0]):
    for j in range(output_shape[1]):
        print(f"Subset at position ({i}, {j}):\n{subsets[i, j]}\n")
```

Comment: This answer would be more helpful if it explained how it answers the question -- code-only answers are never as useful as answers that explain the solution. That said, the question was "*Is there a more efficient way to perform this operation and avoid doing these two loops?*", so code that uses loops is probably not answering the question.

Comment: Can you explain how your answer is so similar to the one generated by ChatGPT?

Comment: how is this better?